# creating array of objects from an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this array

```
[
  [ [ 'id', 'name' ], [ '1', 'A' ] ],
  [ [ 'id', 'name' ], [ '2', 'B' ] ],
  [ [ 'id', 'name' ], [ '3', 'C' ] ]
]
```

and i want it to be  array of object with the corresponding value

```
[{id: 1, name: 'A'}, {id:2, name: 'B'}, {id:3, name: 'C'}]
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) iterate over the array.

For every subarray, it will have a list of `keys` and a list of `values`. Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), you can iterate over `keys` to compute an object with the help of the third parameter, the index, to get each corresponding value:

```js
const data = [
  [ [ 'id', 'name', 'age' ], [ '1', 'A', 22 ] ],
  [ [ 'id', 'name' ], [ '2', 'B' ] ],
  [ [ 'id', 'name' ], [ '3', 'C' ] ]
];

const arr = data.map(([ keys, values = [] ]) => 
  keys.reduce((obj, key, i) => ({ ...obj, [key]: values[i] }), {})
);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: hey Majed thank you so much, but what if the array length is different for example if the array was like this  [ 'id', 'name', age ], [ '1', 'A', 22 ]  i am trying to use them in a function so whatever the two inner arrays' length is i am going to return it as array of objects

Comment: @mohamedali in this case, you need to loop over the first list and get the values from the second so it's dynamic. I updated the answer

Comment: thank you so much Majed, much appreciated

Comment: You're welcome, you can accept the answer as the solution if it solved the problem to close the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use any higher-order functions in js like map, for, reduce. Below is the implementation with [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
const arr = [
 [
   ['id', 'name'],
   ['1', 'A'],
 ],
 [
   ['id', 'name'],
   ['2', 'B'],
 ],
 [
   ['id', 'name'],
   ['3', 'C'],],
 ];


const response = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
   const [firstItem, secondItem] = curr;
   const [id, name] = firstItem;
   const [val1, val2] = secondItem;
   acc.push({ [id]: val1, [name]: val2 });
   return ACC;
}, []);

console.log(response)
```

Comment: thanks, this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

You could transpose the inner arrays and map new objects.

```js
const
    transpose = (a, b) => b.map((v, i) => [...(a[i] || []), v]),
    data = [[['id', 'name'], ['1', 'A'] ], [['id', 'name'], ['2', 'B']], [['id', 'name'], ['3', 'C']]],
    result = data.map(a => Object.fromEntries(a.reduce(transpose, [])));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thank you this was helpful